# How to allow only one vote per device/broswer without alert window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am a newbie Javascripter, i made a upvote and downvote button [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/jmeng/g6Lhurae/)
this code only allows 1 vote per browser, but it opens a alert window. How to close it?

Also i want to give them a option to remove the vote, if they click on the button again. Please help me out.

Comment: Just comment the row with `alert("You already Voted!")`

Comment: Please post the relevant code in the question itself. Links to JSFiddle and the like are fine, but if they go down for whatever reason this question will be unnavigable.

Comment: criz, i did not got you.

Comment: Is this what you want? https://fiddle.jshell.net/w47fwv0d/

Comment: oh yeah, thanks. One more thing, i want to make it so, if i click on upvote/downvote 2 times, it do not count the vote. I mean, if someone click on like in facebook, and then click on it again, he unlikes it..